# Problem with loading dynamic components in Next13 app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic, lazy-loading, next.js13

I want to create dynamic component, which name and props are coming from api, but I get an error. Here's the code.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicComponent = (componentName: string) =>
  dynamic(() => import(`./C${componentName}`));

const CCustomComponent: FC<{ field: any }> = ({ field }) => {
  return React.createElement(DynamicComponent(field.blockType), {
    // @ts-ignore
    field: field,
  });
};

export default CCustomComponent;
```

Here's the errors:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

Call Stack referring to: Object.useContext, useLoadableModule and LoadableComponent in /node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.development.js and
node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/loadable.js

I'm not using any hooks in any of these components.

The problem mostly occurs with:

```
const DynamicComponent = (componentName: string) =>
  dynamic(() => import(`./C${componentName}`));
```

It's also weird, because sometimes it works, and sometimes not. F.e. it's already working on the page that I deployed, but wanted to make some changes, and it stopped working on dev and on build.

Comment: did u use `use client` in ur page?

Comment: No, because it's the last thing I want to do with that. It's also weird, because Next pages approach didn't have this problem.

Comment: then try using 'use client' in this component see whether it works. beta nexjts app approach and pages approach are different since it uses server components, on top of that, it's beta and many issues are not ironed out. If you feel it's not working correctly, you should raise issue in github